# Ecore Modeling Project unavailable

Tags: java, eclipse, model, emf, ecore

I have been following these guides:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/ecoretools/doc/index.html

and after installing EcoreTools and EMF SDK I want to create an "Ecore Modeling Project". Unfortunately it is unavailable in the overview in file->new->other
I only get "Ecore Tools Project", but that doesn't appear to be the same. I also tried the Eclipse Modeling Package, same problem there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: which eclipse IDE do you use? A clean install of the Eclipse Modeling Tools IDE should resolve your issue. [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/neon1rc3) the link to the neon IDE

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of the Ecore Tools package (that is responsible for the class diagram-like editor for Ecore) have slightly different names for the project.

In current versions (e.g. in Eclipse Neon) it is called "Ecore Modeling Project", in some older versions it was called "Ecore Tools Project". Given Ecore Tools received quite a facelift recently, you could finish the tutorial with the older version you are using, there might be a few subtle differences between your tool and the tutorial. For this reason, unless there is some compelling reason not to, I suggest downloading/installing an up-to-date installation.